# How do I find which transaction is causing a "Waiting for table metadata lock" state?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to perform some DDL on a table and `SHOW PROCESSLIST` results in a " Waiting for table metadata lock " message.

How can I find out which transaction is not yet closed?

I'm using MySQL v5.5.24.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

**Works for MySql version < 5.7.3**

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS \G
```

Look for the Section -

```
TRANSACTIONS
```

We can use **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** Tables.

**Useful Queries**

To check about all the locks transactions are waiting for:

```
USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
SELECT * FROM INNODB_LOCK_WAITS;
```

A list of blocking transactions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INNODB_LOCKS 
WHERE LOCK_TRX_ID IN (SELECT BLOCKING_TRX_ID FROM INNODB_LOCK_WAITS);
```

OR

```
SELECT INNODB_LOCKS.* 
FROM INNODB_LOCKS
JOIN INNODB_LOCK_WAITS
  ON (INNODB_LOCKS.LOCK_TRX_ID = INNODB_LOCK_WAITS.BLOCKING_TRX_ID);
```

A List of locks on particular table:

```
SELECT * FROM INNODB_LOCKS 
WHERE LOCK_TABLE = db_name.table_name;
```

A list of transactions waiting for locks:

```
SELECT TRX_ID, TRX_REQUESTED_LOCK_ID, TRX_MYSQL_THREAD_ID, TRX_QUERY
FROM INNODB_TRX
WHERE TRX_STATE = 'LOCK WAIT';
```

**Reference** - [MySQL Troubleshooting: What To Do When Queries Don't Work](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449312004), Chapter 6 - Page 96.

Comment: Just a note that all the tables referenced are in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database.

Comment: Do these InnoDB tables really hold information on metatdata locks? This blog post suggests otherwise: http://mysql.wisborg.dk/2014/01/13/who-holds-the-metadata-lock-mysql-5-7-3-brings-help/

Comment: @Gareth : works till mysql -mysql-5-7-3- .  Thanks for update.

Comment: all of these had empty sets... yet there's still the lock being shown on processlist...

Comment: Check out the comment below https://stackoverflow.com/a/36175882/362574

Comment: Just FYI,  but you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) to do any of these queries.

Comment: Why this answer have so much upvotes? It doesn't answer the question. None of mentioned queries show **metadata** locks...

Answer (score 69):

If you cannot find the process locking the table (cause it is alreay dead), it may be a thread still cleaning up like this

section TRANSACTION of

```
show engine innodb status;
```

at the end

```
---TRANSACTION 1135701157, ACTIVE 6768 sec
MySQL thread id 5208136, OS thread handle 0x7f2982e91700, query id 882213399 xxxIPxxx 82.235.36.49 my_user cleaning up
```

as mentionned in a comment in
[Clear transaction deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462249/clear-transaction-deadlock)

you can try killing the transaction thread directly,
here with

```
 KILL 5208136;
```

worked for me.

Comment: If you are stuck on Mysql 5.6 or less this is the only solution, unfortunately. You forced to guess the right transaction from the list. For example, you can look at `ACTIVE` time of each transaction and try to kill the transaction with biggest time value. **This is not safe, of course, as you could guess wrong and kill a wrong transaction...**

Answer (score 25):

mysql 5.7 exposes metadata lock information through the  `performance_schema.metadata_locks` table.

Documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-metadata-locks-table.html)

Answer (score 13):

For MySQL version >= `5.7.3` the Performance Schema now exposes metadata lock information.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-3.html

Run this query to know who holds your metadata locks

```
SELECT OBJECT_TYPE,
       OBJECT_SCHEMA,
       OBJECT_NAME,
       LOCK_TYPE,
       LOCK_STATUS,
       THREAD_ID,
       PROCESSLIST_ID,
       PROCESSLIST_INFO
FROM performance_schema.metadata_locks
INNER JOIN performance_schema.threads ON THREAD_ID = OWNER_THREAD_ID
WHERE PROCESSLIST_ID <> CONNECTION_ID();
```

---

When I tried to run the query in the accepted answer, I received this:

```
Empty set, 1 warning (0.001 sec)
```

Checking that 1 warning, I found that `INNODB_LOCK_WAITS` is deprecated.

```
MySQL [ebdb]> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                                       |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1681 | 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCK_WAITS' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This helped. On AWS Aurora 2 (MySQL 5.7 compatible), I had to use this procedure to kill the offending threads: https://oracle-base.com/articles/mysql/mysql-killing-threads#killing-threads

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue with Datagrip and none of these solutions worked.

Once I restarted the Datagrip Client it was no longer an issue and I could drop tables again.

Comment: restart/reboot - the 100% working solution for any computer issues. However, in Prod, reboots aren't always possible

Comment: I had the same problem and closing DataGrip suddenly dropped all of the locks. That's a bunch of wasted time..

Comment: Had the same issue with MySQL Workbench and restarting also worked

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem and none of the queries above showed any lock.
But I had an alter locked with this " Waiting for table metadata lock " message.
I found there was a long running query (it was running for more than two hours). I killed that query and the alter unlocked immediately.

Answer (score -1):

None of these answers totally worked for me on Mysql 5.6. For locking transactions that don't show up in process list, I had to use

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS \G
```

And look in the `Transactions` section as others have suggested. Usually the bottom row of transactions should be something not too old like

```
---TRANSACTION 1746333130055, ACTIVE 20 sec
MySQL thread id 2078245871, OS thread handle 0x7fb1ab3bb700, query id 64608927411 10.0.200.123 app_user
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 1746333130056, sees < 1746332958368
```

But sometimes it might look more like

```
---TRANSACTION 1742251019746, ACTIVE 283392 sec
230145 lock struct(s), heap size 29685288, 1531889 row lock(s), undo log entries 1527774
MySQL thread id 1891102408, OS thread handle 0x7f7d8c132700, query id 59116541146 10.0.200.224 app_user
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 1742251019747, sees < 1742250438378
```

^ Note the `283392 sec` indicating that this transaction is the culprit of the locked table. The associated process is labeled as the "thread id", which is `1891102408` in this case. To root cause what about that process has caused the lock, I run from the command line of the db server:

```
mysql -u root -e 'show processlist' | grep "1891102408"
```

Which indicates which server the query originated from, along with the a unique identifier (the port number), like:

```
32907376794 app_user    10.0.200.224:46092  production_database Sleep   124144      NULL    0   1
```

After logging in to the 10.0.200.224 server, one can use `netstat -apN | grep 46092` to see which process on the server is responsible for the Mysql process and kill it from its source, debugging what went wrong to whatever extent desired.