# Checking status of a Transaction - MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I want to use Transactions in MySQL, my questions is that How I can check if the queries are submitted successfully or not? my query is:

```
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
$query_1 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM BLAH WHERE BLAH");
$query_2 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM BLAH WHERE BLAH");
mysql_query("COMMIT");
```

as far as I know, the above code does the transaction, but I want to check if the queries are submitted successfully or not, so:

```
    mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
    $query_1 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM BLAH WHERE BLAH");
    $query_2 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM BLAH WHERE BLAH");
    if($query_1 && $query_2){
       mysql_query(COMMIT);
    }else{
       mysql_query(ROLLBACK);
    }
```

But I read somewhere that in transactions, the queries submit when we call "`COMMIT`", so the above code should not work since while we check `$query_1 && $query_2`, actually nothing is submitted to db since it's before the "`COMMIT`" query, how I could perform such check?

Thanks in advance

P.S: Am I doing the whole thing right? please kindly let me know if there are also some other better ways... thanks

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148630/how-do-i-find-which-transaction-is-causing-a-waiting-for-table-metadata-lock-s/13155778#13155778

Comment: this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are performing `DELETE` commands, you'll be able to see if there was any affected rows by calling the [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) function.

> **mysql_affected_rows** — Get number of affected rows in previous MySQL operation

There is even [mention of use in conjunction with transactions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php#example-1615) in the documentation -

> **Note: Transactions** If you are using transactions, you need to call
>   mysql_affected_rows() after your INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE query, not
>   after the COMMIT.

---

It should be noted here that you are using an old version of database connections. See the php documentation on any page related to `mysql_*` commands and you'll encounter this message -

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: how would he know that how many rows will be affected so that he can confirm that the transaction has been made successfully?

Comment: @pru - The number of rows affected would have to be matched against the number of intended deletions.

Comment: @Lix and in general, what if I'm not deleting!? what if I'm just inserting in multiple tables...? what if `AUTOCOMMIT = 0`, where should I use `AUTOCOMMIT = 0`? thanks

Comment: @beh - If you are inserting, then you'd look at [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).

Comment: IF you are looking for general errors you could also take a look at `mysql_error()`.

Comment: @Lix my argument is, he may not be able to determine every time how many rows will be deleted depending on the query. so that he can assume that "k 60 rows have been affected as i thought" so the transaction has run fine.

Comment: @pru, for that kind of confirmation you would need to do a `SELECT count(*)` with the same parameters to check how many records match the search criteria.

Comment: @pru - Deleting 0 records because no records were found matching the search criteria could also be a success... It all depends on the context.

Comment: @Lix AFAIK transactions are generally used to update or modify data in database not to retrieve. Nothing will stop you to do otherwise.

Comment: @Lix haha we should take this to some private chat or chat room but have to leave.