# When using 32bit version of MySQL's .net connector to connect to a 64bit version of MySQL I get " Waiting for table metadata lock "

Tags: mysql, .net, 32bit-64bit, mysql-connector

I have .net application that is compiled with 'AnyCPU' flag. This application uses MySQL for persistent storage.

I have run into a strange problem i.e. When I run my application on a 32 bit machine and hook it to 64 bit version of MySQL running on a different machine, my queries end up in state " Waiting for table metadata lock ".

I have already tested that it works fine when both, my application and MySQL, are running on the same platform i.e. both on 32bit or both on 64bit.

Here is my theory which can be totally wrong :)

Since my application is loaded as 32 bit application, consequently the .net connector assembly (which I presume is compiled with 'anycpu') will  be loaded as 32 bit as well. My guess here is that something goes wrong when a 32bit .net connector communicates with 64bit MySQL.

Is my theory correct?

a) If no, please let me know, what would be the easiest way to find out whats going wrong?

b) if yes, what can I do about it. The reason being I can't force the .net framework to load mysql's .net connector assembly in 64bit mode for my 32bit application. Even if that was possible ( within the same process), how in the world am I going to know, before loading the connector, what type of MySQL will my application be connecting to ....?

P.S. My gut feeling is that its highly unlikely that this theory is correct as according to Google, no else has encountered this problem before.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like it has anything to do with 64/32 bit from the error message given.

Have a look at this SO question and answer and see if that gives any clues: [How do I find which transaction is causing a "Waiting for table metadata lock" state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148630/how-do-i-find-which-transaction-is-causing-a-waiting-for-table-metadata-lock-s)

Comment: Yes, I did have a look at the question that you linked before posting this question. But it didn't help.