# Python's MySQLdb stuck during TRUNCATE statement

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I try to do the following: `cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE words")` (using a connection `con` and a cursor `cur` = `con.cursor` that worked elsewhere).

The strange thing is, it worked with other tables. I tried to do `cur.execute("SET_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1")` first, but that doesn't work either. What could be going wrong?

Comment: What are the symptoms? Any errors? What about the logs on the database side?

Comment: Have you checked the server status? Might be a metadata lock, or similar. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13148630/2359271