# How to see a list of Locks from a MySql Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, locking, rdbms

I have a very large sql query. How do I see a list of all the locks that it sets during execution in MySQL/MariaSQL InnoDB?

Answer (score 1):

There are some INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables for this:

- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCK_WAITS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-lock-waits-table.html)
- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCKS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-table.html)

In general, you can't get a list of locks, unless there's a lock-wait in progress.

That is, transaction A can hold some number of locks, but unless some transaction B is stuck waiting for it, it doesn't show up in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

See also [How do I find which transaction is causing a "Waiting for table metadata lock" state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148630/how-do-i-find-which-transaction-is-causing-a-waiting-for-table-metadata-lock-s/23757255)

Comment: So in other words, this can only display the looked-for results if you queried these tables at the exact right time-spot during the execution of your analyzing query?

Comment: Hmmmm.... Can this be used in a more useful way for queries running under 0.1sec? Can somehow the progression/changes of this data be shown?

Comment: I don't know any way to do so.