# AWS RDS Mysql kill transaction by ID (without thread_id)

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I'm currently having an issue with some long running transactions that are holding locks to a single row in a table that I'm being unable to kill.

Innodb_trx holds the following information - special attention to thread_id = null;

```
select * from information_schema.innodb_trx\G
*************************** 2. row ***************************
                    trx_id: 153261728
                 trx_state: RUNNING
               trx_started: 2019-10-02 10:05:42
     trx_requested_lock_id: NULL
          trx_wait_started: NULL
                trx_weight: 5
       trx_mysql_thread_id: 0
                 trx_query: NULL
       trx_operation_state: NULL
         trx_tables_in_use: 0
         trx_tables_locked: 2
          trx_lock_structs: 3
     trx_lock_memory_bytes: 1136
           trx_rows_locked: 1
         trx_rows_modified: 2
   trx_concurrency_tickets: 0
       trx_isolation_level: READ COMMITTED
         trx_unique_checks: 1
    trx_foreign_key_checks: 1
trx_last_foreign_key_error: NULL
 trx_adaptive_hash_latched: 0
 trx_adaptive_hash_timeout: 0
          trx_is_read_only: 0
trx_autocommit_non_locking: 0
```

and

```
show engine innodb status\G;
------------------
---TRANSACTION 153261728, ACTIVE (PREPARED) 27716 sec recovered trx
3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
---TRANSACTION 96697370, ACTIVE (PREPARED) 988082 sec recovered trx
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
```

Is there as way to kill/stop/rollback a transaction like this?

Comment: Transaction/queries still in `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` aswell ?   KILL works on `CONNECTION_ID()` and not thread_id

Comment: @RaymondNijland unfortunately there is no process in the full processlist.

Comment: Are these XA transactions?  I don't think I've ever run across anyone using them, but that's what it looks like... https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/09/22/how-to-deal-with-xa-transactions-recovery/

Comment: @JoãoSalavisa how did you end up solving this?

Answer (score -1):

I have a stored query that I commonly use to do this on rds that looks like the following:

```
SELECT CONCAT('CALL mysql.rds_kill( ',id,');') kill_cmd, p.*
FROM information_schema.processlist p WHERE DB='yourDb';
```

[image]
This generates a kill statement for all active processes. In your case you just want one (or possibly a few) ids, so from there you can copy-paste the `kill` statement that you want based on the id(s). For example, you'd run the following to kill process `1991542`:

```
CALL mysql.rds_kill(1991542);
```

Comment: OP statest that the process does not show up in processlist